# Pulling only required columns in Spark from Cassandra without loading all the columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Using the spark-elasticsearch connector it is possible to directly load only the required columns from ES to Spark. However, there doesn't seem to exist such a straight forward option to do the same, using the spark-cassandra connector

Reading data from ES into Spark
-- here only required columns are being brought from ES to Spark :

```
spark.conf.set('es.nodes', ",".join(ES_CLUSTER))
es_epf_df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
        .option("es.read.field.include", "id_,employee_name") \
        .load("employee_0001") \
```

Reading data from Cassandra into Spark
-- here all the columns' data is brought to spark and then select is applied to pull columns of interest :

```
spark.conf.set('spark.cassandra.connection.host', ','.join(CASSANDRA_CLUSTER))
cass_epf_df = spark.read.format('org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra') \
        .options(keyspace="db_0001", table="employee") \
        .load() \
        .select("id_", "employee_name")
```

Is it possible to do the same for Cassandra? If yes, then how. If not, then why not.

Comment: As Rayan correctly pointed - it's done by connector after all select/filtering are applied to the data - it will read only necessary columns.   `spark.read` itself doesn't trigger the immediate reading of the data, it happens later when connector can decide what data is really needed to be pulled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, connector should do that itself, without need to explicitly set anything, it's called "predicate pushdown", and cassandra-connector does it, according to documentation:

> The connector will automatically pushdown all valid predicates to
>   Cassandra. The Datasource will also *automatically only select columns
>   from Cassandra which are required* to complete the query.  This can be
>   monitored with the explain command.

source: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md

Answer (score 1):

The code which you have written is already doing that. You have written select after load and you may think first all the columns are pulled and then selected columns are filtered, but that is not the case.

Assumption : `select * from db_0001.employee;`

Actual : `select id_, employee_name from db_0001.employee;`

Spark will understand the columns which you need and query only those in Cassandra database. This feature is called predicate pushdown. This is not limited just to cassandra, many sources support this feature(this is a feature of spark, not casssandra).

For more info: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkPredicatePushdown.html